# Splitting Angular Dependencies in to separate bundle files

Tags: angular, performance, webpack, server-side-rendering, webpack-splitchunks

My website is an Angular SPA with SSR that works perfectly. To lazy load the components based on the path, I used lazy loaded modules.

Because of the libraries I use, my main.js file is roughly 3MB, which increases the Total Blocking Time (TBT) on pagespeed insights.
I'll have to separate **main.js** into multiple files to lessen the TBT.
Is it possible to bundle files like `angular-core.bundle.js, angular-material.bundle.js, and chart-js.bundle.js`?

I heard that this could be done using the **splitchunksplugin**, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Please assist me in achieving this.

Comment: are you looking for [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading)?

Comment: No. I had already implemented lazy loading. I need to split the vendor bundle.

Comment: Your library has no "split" modules?. I want to say that, e.g. ng-bootstrap you can import all the library or only the modules you need in each moment (material angular use the same)

Comment: I'm using the required modules alone.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same now. You can solve it by refactoring your library to [use an entrypoint per module](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/commit/bd72156b6d56ad6d474ec065e047f2974e7c152c#diff-ad421895d3e8c7efee57da8d90183eac32ba42a512108e401a7487417505fd5aL3-R4)